# Data integrity in JSON(B) when replacing EAV

Tags: json, django, database

I'm implementing a database for a new application and I'm considering using `JSON` fields instead of traditional `EAV` approach. Everything seems okay, but there is a one **big problem** that I don't know how to solve.

For example; in a traditional `EAV` model, we would have three tabels;

- First table to hold the attributes
- Second table to hold the values
- Third table to tie those two together.

The identifier in the **third table** would always be primary key of one of the other two and not the value itself. If I change the name of the attribute, it's primary key remains the same thus having no affect on the data integrity in the **third table**.

Now  enter `JSON`. As far as I understand, the whole point of replacing `EAV` with `JSON` is to store all the values in the fields itself. So our record could look like this.

```
{
   "color": "Blue",
   "size": "Large"
}
```

instead of storing values by primary keys.

So my question is, if I down the road, change the title of the color from let's say `Blue` to `Purple`, how do I deal with data integrity? Since in classic `EAV` model the primary keys wouldn't change.

I'm using `Postgresql` database with `Django`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Django ORM, the only way to manipulate the values of JSON fields is to 
iterate over the models. But you can query/filter for individual fields:

Let's assume you have this model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models

class Thing(models.Model):
    attributes = JSONField()
```

You should be able to query for blue things (see [Querying JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield)):

```
blue_things = Thing.objects.filter(attributes__color='Blue')
```

Now you can iterate over these model instances and update the value:

```
for thing in blue_things:
    thing.attributes['color'] = 'Purple'
    thing.save()
```

You might want to do that within a transaction.

PostgreSQL allows you to manipulate JSONB fields directly:

```
UPDATE appname_thing SET attributes = attributes || '{"color": "Purple"}' WHERE attributes->>'color' = 'Blue';
```

As far as I know, this is currently not supported by Django, so you would have to [perform a raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not acquainted with Django personally, but if you wanted to take advantage of PostgreSQL's JSON functionality, I'd probably rely on a primary key column separate from your more arbitrary JSON.  Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE stuff (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    data JSON NOT NULL
);
```

That way you've got your `id` column as a reliable reference and can do whatever you like with the JSON.  If you have a known/predictable structure to the JSON, you can [create indices](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) to help with performance when querying *into* the JSON data.

**Original Answer:**

It's not clear to me what database product you're going to use, but being familiar with MongoDB, a JSON document-oriented database, I can tell you how it works there.  When you insert a document, if you don't supply it an `_id` field is added with what MongoDB calls an [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).  So, if you inserted your sample JSON, you'd have something like:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5d97d46a54198e0797d86457"),
   "color": "Blue",
   "size": "Large"
}
```

If you wanted to update just that document, you could use the `_id` in the "where clause" like:

```
db.collection.updateOne({
   _id: ObjectId("5d97d46a54198e0797d86457")
}, {
    $set: {
        color: "Red",
        size: "Medium"
    }
});
```

Again, not knowing what DB you're using, this could be way off base.  If you're dealing with JSONB in something like PostgreSQL then you'd typically include a `serial` or similar column to maintain a fixed primary keep, like you mention.

Comment: I've edited the original question, thanks for your answer.